# node_delete() is not deleting nodes

Tags: 6, nodes, drush

I'm trying to use a drush function to flush out all of the drealty module's nodes in my drupal 6 install.  However, something is causing a memory leak and the nodes are not being deleted after node_delete is called.  What can I do?

Here is the memory exhausted error:

```
drush rets-flush
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /home/directory/public_html/sites/all/modules/filefield/field_file.inc on line 300
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 71 bytes) in
/home/directory/public_html/sites/all/modules/filefield/field_file.inc,
line 300
```

Here is the drush rets-flush function:

```php
function drush_drealty_rets_flush() {
  set_time_limit(0);

  $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = 'drealty_property' OR type = 'drealty_agent' OR type = 'drealty_office' OR type = 'drealty_open_house'", $conid);

  $count = 0;
  while ($nid = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    node_delete($nid->nid);
    drush_log(dt('Deleting node id: @nid. ', array('@nid' => $nid->nid)));
    $count++;
  }
  drush_log(dt('Deleted @count nodes', array('@count' => $count)), 'success');
}
```

There are about 5000 records total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find that you still run out of memory if you have enough nodes of the drealty type.  This is because `node_delete()` calls `node_load()`, and that adds each node to a static cache.  If you run into this, simply call `node_load(NULL, NULL, TRUE)` once every 50 - 100 iterations.

Comment: Thanks justintime, I'll remember to add this code as a patch to the drealty project if I ever experience the issue again.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself.  I had to run drush as admin:

```bsh
drush -u admin rets-flush
```

I thought drush ran as admin automatically, but I guess not.